# How to fix "Non-OK-status: Not found: Op type not registered 'NoOp' in binary running" in tensorflow

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow r1.9 on Windows 10/VisualStudio with a pure C++ API. I try to save and reload a trained model.
I found at
https://github.com/rockzhuang/tensorflow/commit/fb6a6f4e3dd6e663a14b672ab5c616d968d62bc5#diff-a46c94d7dc93c6f7a3b632dc14e46479
an example how to save a model, therefore I added all functions and links into my release (since on Windows 10 I can't install a higher version than r1.9)
I managed it to compile and run the program with my application, but now I get this Run-time-error:

`2019-04-30 09:08:55.571067: F D:\src\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\graph\graph.cc:287] Non-OK-status: status status: Not found: Op type not registered 'NoOp' in binary running on TBK-SW19. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) 'tf.contrib.resampler' should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.`

The error occurs in the constructor (graph.cc:287, AddNode - function):

```
Graph::Graph(const OpRegistryInterface* ops)
    : ops_(ops, FunctionDefLibrary()),
      versions_(new VersionDef),
      arena_(8 << 10 /* 8kB */) {
  versions_->set_producer(TF_GRAPH_DEF_VERSION);
  versions_->set_min_consumer(TF_GRAPH_DEF_VERSION_MIN_CONSUMER);

  // Initialize the name interning table for assigned_device_name.
  device_names_.push_back("");
  DCHECK_EQ(0, InternDeviceName(""));

  // Source and sink have no endpoints, just control edges.
  NodeDef def;
  def.set_name("_SOURCE");
  def.set_op("NoOp");
  Status status;
  Node* source = AddNode(def, &status);
  TF_CHECK_OK(status);
  CHECK_EQ(source->id(), kSourceId);

  def.set_name("_SINK");
  Node* sink = AddNode(def, &status);
  TF_CHECK_OK(status);
  CHECK_EQ(sink->id(), kSinkId);

  AddControlEdge(source, sink);
}
```

I would expect a linking problem (not registered kernels), but the error message is (at least for me) a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I can answer my own question.
During build/setup of my system, I tried a lot of different things, and (o course) I didn't undo one of those tests, which lead to this error message.

Particulary, I linked with

- \tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\Release\pywrap_tensorflow_internal_static.lib
- \tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\Release\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib

I removed those lib's --> after a rebuild, the program runs.